# SetHomeButtonEnabled not working but setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled is working

Tags: android

I want to add the application icon in the actionbar for all the activities in my application and on the icon click , I would like to navigate to the home page of my application.

I tried with the following code in onCreate

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Now the application icon is coming in the actionbar , but on clicking it, onOptionsItemSelected is not getting called. But if use actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) instead of actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true) , onOptionsItemSelected is getting called with item.getItemId() . Below is the code snippet

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The documentation says using both setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled and setHomeButtonEnabled , onOptionsItemSelected  will be called and the only difference is the up arrow. I dont need the up arrow in the actionbar, I only require the application icon. How can that be done?

My minSdkVersion 14 and targetSdkVersion 21.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)

You can use:

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and this should replace the back arrow with your icon

Comment: any idea why ```setHomeButtonEnabled``` is not working?

Comment: @JiechaoWang what is your use case?

Comment: @kandroidj I've also got the same issue. `actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`. Still back is not working..

Answer (score 6):

you can use this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
    finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);`

fist code shows left arrow on toolbar and second code lets you to put your icon

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using Toolbar we probably should use:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(@DrawableRes int resId)
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener)
```

setHomeButtonEnabled does not work for ToolbarActionBar according to sources of androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1:

```
class ToolbarActionBar extends ActionBar {
    @Override
    public void setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        // If the nav button on a Toolbar is present, it's enabled. No-op.
    }
```